# JSF IllegalException: Component ID form: `xyz` has already been found in the view

Tags: jsf, file-upload, icefaces

I am getting `IllegalStateException` saying component ID form has already been found in the view and am not sure what is causing this issue and I do not want this exception in the first place.

**Exception**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Component ID form:_captureFileOnsubmit has already been found in the view.
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:846) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:830) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.saveView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:135) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:133) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
```

My `xhtml` page looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"   xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/icefaces/ace-jquery.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/icefaces/ace-components.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/icefaces/icepush.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/icefaces/bridge.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/icefaces/compat.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/icefaces/fileEntry.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/icefaces/jsf.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/icefaces/icefaces-compat.js" />

    <h:head>
        <title>ICEfaces 3</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
             <h:form id="form">
                <h:outputText value="Welcome to ICEfaces 3, select current date: "/>
                <ace:dateTimeEntry renderAsPopup="true">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" timeZone="Canada/Mountain"/>
                </ace:dateTimeEntry>
                <ace:fileEntry id = "fileUpload"
                               label="File Entry"
                               relativePath="uploaded"
                               fileEntryListener="#{fileUpload.uploadFile}"/>
             <h:commandButton value="Upload File" />
             </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

All am trying to do is just get `fileUpload` feature working, wierd part is that `javascript` and `css` stuffs present in `javax.faces.resources` folder is not referenced in the application and so there are some of wierd errors that i get.

Another thing to note is if I use `eclipse` with `icefaces` plugins then `fileUplaod` feature works fine but if i try to build them without plugins and with only standard set of required jars then i am getting componenet id related IllegalStateException.

Any thoughts, suggestinos?

**Updates**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>com.icesoft.faces.blockingRequestHandler</param-name>
<param-value>icefaces</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>com.icesoft.faces.checkJavaScript</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: What are those `<script>` elements doing there?

Comment: @BalusC: Issue am facing is somehow icefaces resources are not getting referenced in my application and so what i am doing right now is to add those resources js and css file in separate folder and referencing them in `xhtml` page, i know this is not right way of doing it but am not sure of any other way.

Comment: Sounds like you've more problems with how the project and/or environment is been setup. You shouldn't workaround the symptoms/side-effects, you should solve the problem by its roots.

Comment: @BalusC: It's an legacy application, also would like to pick your brain on what pieces you thing are more troublesome and what would be your suggestions for the same.

Comment: @BalusC: For time being, if i restart my application then i do not see those exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get errors like this using mojarra when I have javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE set to Development. If you have this set change it to Production and see if the errors go away.

I though it was known bug but can't find anything.

Comment: Where exactly are you having this settings?

Comment: would be context-param in web.xml

Comment: @thejosh-I have updated question with `context param` information.